# How hidden are you to a network admin

Tags: networking

So to be more specific, I am aware that an admin can see your browser history and stuff but can they see what you do in cmd and if you run cmd in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather vague. Do you have a specific question here? As a general rule, an administrator account exists to keep tabs on all actions performed on the host in question. The administrator would have access to whatever histories, file systems and commands you may have executed, added, deleted, etc.. In some cases, the logging level may be turned down, but I would never assume that your actions are invisible to an administrator account.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question perfectly.